# SOAP response showing error-SAAJ Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, saaj

I am having one function where we generate SOAP request.The request I am able to run in SOAP UI tool and its fetching.

I am creating SOAPMessage like this

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
headers.removeAllHeaders();
headers.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
```

When I call

```
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, url);
```

get this error:

> SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?

could you help to sort it out?
whether that means connection unable to establish??

Answer (score 0):

Most probably expected HTTP `Content-Type` header for SOAP messages is `application/soap+xml` (see [XML SOAP](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp)).

The exception you get originates from SOAP service container saying that the value of `Content-Type` header is `text/html`. I think that SOAP UI set the correct request header value for you.

The header value sent by your code seem to be a default one. You should check what the expected `Content-Type` value is for you server and ho to set it with your framework/library.

Comment: i am adding like this MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.removeAllHeaders();
          headers.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

Comment: This is normal. Can you add info about the SAAJ implementation (or application server) you are using. Seems to be configuration related.

Comment: its a standalone java code on eclipse.pLEASE SEE THE CODE Ffor SOAP implementation

Comment: The case here is not 100% as yours, but there we figured out that `Content-Type` is automatically set by SAAJ by SOAP protocol. And seems this is only thing that matters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47600370/unable-to-set-content-type-on-soap-request/47601111#47601111

Comment: This even more convinces me that you issue is connected to framework or environment configuration.

Comment: can i know any specific enivronment configuration or setting for this